# Display images in a folder using PHP

Tags: php, html

Ok, been looking all over the internet and even Stackoverflow but I can't seem to get the following PHP code to work.

```
<div class="grid">
<ul class="images">
<?php
//path to directory to open
$directory = "/Media/pics/";
$dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("Unable to open folder");

while(false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle)))
{
  if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'Thumbs.db') 
  {
    echo "<li class='picture' title='Remote2'> <img src='/Media/pics/".$file."'alt='test'/></li>";                      
  }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

Each time I try and view the page, I get:

403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access **intranet/Media/pics/".$file."** on this server.

Yet I am able to navigate to "intanet/Media/pics" and see and click on all the images in the folder.
I don't think it is a permission issue, but maybe something I'm missing in the PHP code. Makes me wish I had a really good PHP editor with syntax highlighting and auto-complete (currently using Aptana Studio 3).

Thanks for the help!

**SOLUTION:** Had to do the following:
1) Change "pictures.html" to "pictures.php" (newb mistake)

2) Fix the realitive path from "/media/pics" to just "media/pics"

Comment: If the server's response has `$file` in it, I'd think that the PHP was being sent without being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments to the answer of @Marc B.

The PHP scripts in the file did not seems to be executed. Did you name the file correctly?

In order for the PHP screpts to be ran, you need to give the file a ".php" extension. I suspect you might have names it as ".html"?

Or is it the configuration on the Apache is not set up correctly to run ".php" files past PHP?

Comment: See, this is why I like StackOverflow, now we maybe getting somewhere. I changed the "pictures.html" to "pictures.php" and when I ran that, I got only processed html back before the PHP code (basically only saw the "PICTURE" header and part of the CSS). So I looked at the source and saw "unable to open folder" right where my PHP code was. So now I'm thinking that there is some kind of permissions issue with that folder. Now to figure out how to give PHP access to that folder...

Comment: BINGO! Turns out that it could not find the directory because it was "media/pics" and not "/media/pics" (I should have at least caught that error from the get go, can't believe I over looked that!). Once I changed that and made sure the file was ".php" not ".html" it worked beautifully. Thanks to everyone who helped me fix this issue, ya'll rock!!

Answer (score 2):

You're using an absolute path, something like `/Media/pics/somepic.jpg`. Do you have a `/Media` directory in the root of your file system? As well, is that /Media folder part of your website's document root? Remember that PHP's file operations work at the file system level, not at your webserver's URL level. PHP can access files that are completely outside of your website's reach, so outputting a file system direct as a URL for a `src` can quite easily point at a file that is impossible for a remote user to access.

Comment: I checked my apache_error.log (running WAMP by the way) and it said:


(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET /Media/pics/%22.$file.%22 HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://intranet/pictures.html


It seems like the PHP is not being processed as Alex said. I'm new to using WAMP and PHP (comming from asp.net) so any help on how I can check to see if PHP has permission to run on the folder it is in? By the way, everything resides under "C:\WAMP\www\Intranet" on the web server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems generally restrict file reading permissions by default. If you know how to CHMOD, make sure that PHP has permission to read that directory. (640 should be enough if Apache is the owner of them. If not, you can try higher, but for reading you shouldn't need higher than 700 or 750.)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
echo "<li class='picture' title='Remote2'> <img src='/Media/pics/".$file."'alt='test'/></li>";
```

to

```
echo "<li class='picture' title='Remote2'> <img src='/Media/pics/$file' alt='test'/></li>";
```

Your error is kind of strange if it's treating the variable name as a string. Double quotes will use the value of $file so this should at least get us a different error if it doesn't work.

Edit: Also I suspect the path might be missing something as has already been mentioned. Compare your path to the path mentioned in the error and see if you have the whole thing in there correctly. For example should it be /home/site/Media/pics (as an example)

Comment: Now I get "The requested URL /Media/pics/$file was not found on this server."


EDIT: Apache_error showing: "GET /Media/pics/$file HTTP/1.1" 404 214